# What are the allowed types for an enum (class)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When declaring an enum (class) I can specify the underlying type that the enum will use, e.g.

```
enum class MyEnum : baseType { FIRST, SECOND };
```

What can `baseType` be? The usual choice would be `uint32_t` or something similar but could it also be `float`? Or even my own class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `N4140 [dcl.enum]/2:` [...] **The type-specifier-seq of an enum-base shall name an integral type; any cv-qualification is ignored.** [...]

So `baseType` can be any integral type, i.e. `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t` and the signed and unsigned integer types.